# How can i get the URL value from a SafeResourceUrl (

Tags: angular, typescript

I cannot believe this question has not been asked. I'm either the first, or there's a good reason it is not in the SO DB already.

I have a sanitized URL, that is now a SafeResourceUrl object. I can log the damned thing and see my URL, but if i try and extract the URL, i get errors and xss reference links.

for example(from the `console.log(safeUrl)`):

```
SafeResourceUrlImpl {changingThisBreaksApplicationSecurity: "https://www.index.html"}
```

I'm new in Angular so please forgive if a dumb question. I have tried targeting the SafeResourceUrlImpl as a property of my variable that holds the SafeResourceurl object, i have tried targeting the changingThisBreaks... key. I know this value type is something different than a standard object and there is probably an easy way to do it.

can someone help me, or better yet explain what i lack in knowledge about this mystical value type.

thanks!

Comment: why do you want to extract the value?

Comment: i need to validate something comes from that origin. its an event listener, and i only want to report events from that URL.

Comment: From the [angular srcs](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/src/sanitization/bypass.ts#L98) there seems to be a function called `unwrapSafeValue` that returns a string - (accessible via `import ɵunwrapSafeValue as unwrapSafeValue from "@angular/core"`)

Comment: @EliasSchablowski if that works i'll let you know so you can answer the question and get credit. i'll try it monday. thanks for the ocmment